# Unable to get socket.io to start on the client side

Tags: javascript, socket.io, typescript

I'm trying to get socket.io to start on the client side that uses JQuery and typescript, but I'm unable to do so. I got the Typescript definition for socket.io from here. (The one updated yesterday.)

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/socket.io/socket.io.d.ts

Here's the code:

```
var socket:Socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

Here's the error I'm getting in the console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined Start.ts:48
socketTest Start.ts:48
start Start.ts:11
(anonymous function) config.ts:24
i.execCb require.js:29
X.check require.js:18
(anonymous function) require.js:23
(anonymous function) require.js:8
(anonymous function) require.js:23
y require.js:7
X.emit require.js:23
X.check require.js:19
X.enable require.js:23
X.init require.js:17
D require.js:14
i.completeLoad require.js:28
i.onScriptLoad
```

--Update-- 
The .ts file loading problem I mentioned earlier is now solved.

Comment: You should start with the problem where the browser is downloading .ts instead of .js, since it's obviously not going to run. Trying to diagnose anything before that is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have accidentally included the TypeScript definition for socket.io rather than the JavaScript library...

```
<script src="scripts/socket.d.ts"></script>
<script src="scripts/start.ts"></script>
```

Should be:

```
<script src="scripts/socket.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/start.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm loading everything using RequireJS. Interestingly I noticed I'm not loading socket.io at all - which I need to do using RequireJS. Do you know where can I find socket.io.js? Doesn't seem available on the website.

Comment: The full socket.io download has the client version included as it's often served from the socket.io server.